# Force Visual Studio 2022 to only display icons instead of window titles

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When you compress one of the window groups in Visual Studio far enough, the window titles will change to icons like so:

[image]

Is there any way to have it like this permanently? It's a lot easier on the eyes than having tons of text all over the place.

EDIT: I found [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegTarasov.Iconizer2022) extension. From the looks of it, this is doing exactly what I want. It is using the built-in icons from VS. I will still leave this open in the hopes that there is another way of achieving this, maybe without needing to install a extension.